# Hide divs simultaneously depending on the largest size

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I have two divs. Inside each div, there are two divs:
[image]

```
<div class="hide">
    <div>
        Variable size
    </div>
    <div>
        Text1 (also variable size)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hide">
    <div>
        Different variable size
    </div>
    <div>
        Text2 (also variable size)
    </div>
</div>
```

If the screen is too small, I want the texts to disappear:
[image]

To do it, I used

```
.hide {
   display: flex;
   height: 100px;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, if the 1st text is too big, but the second is not, I have something like that:
[image]

And I'd like them to be hidden simultaneously.

Is there a way (no jQuery) to do it? Preferably with CSS or SASS, but JS (I use Angular) would also be acceptable.

Comment: I think that is beyond what is possible with CSS alone, if I was in your situation I would probably use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) on both elements. When one of them wraps to the next line in the flexbox and is therefore overflowing you can also hide the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Use display flex like this

```
.hide { height: 100px;  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: I forgot the `display: flex`. Yes, that's what I already did and it produces the problem I mentioned...

Comment: I had already done it, I just forgot to copy it in my question. No, it doesn't work :-(